# RStudio-Type Outline in VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a similar feature in VSCode to the "Outline" feature in RStudio. For example. in RStudio I can create hierarchical sections in my code like the following:

```
# Setup ---
(code here)

# Section 1 ---
(code here)

## Subsection ---
(code here)

# Section 2 ---
(code here)
```

and the rstudio outline will populate an outline like

```
Setup
Section 1
   Subsection
Section 2
```

I can also fold/collapse the sections within the code.

Does anyone know of any similar functionality in VSCode? The native "outline" functionality only seems to work with functions, not user-defined sections. The Region Viewer extension doesn't seem to be compatible with R, and the Code Mapping extension also seems to only work with functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions that can help but they only work on .Rmd and .md files, thus the need for a snippet. There are instructions on how to implement a snippet that will do what you are requesting in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555668/is-it-possible-to-divide-your-code-into-sections-for-r-in-vscode).